# Build failed in ionic when upgrade from android 9 to android 10

Tags: html, angular, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Some problems were found with the configuration of task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices' (type 'GoogleServicesTask').

  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'intermediateDir' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @OutputDirectory.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add a getter for field 'intermediateDir'.
    2. Remove the annotations on 'intermediateDir'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR1' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR1'.
    2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR1'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'packageNameXOR2' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @Input.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add a getter for field 'packageNameXOR2'.
    2. Remove the annotations on 'packageNameXOR2'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
  - In plugin 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin' type 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask' field 'quickstartFile' without corresponding getter has been annotated with @InputFile, @Optional.

    Reason: Annotations on fields are only used if there's a corresponding getter for the field.

    Possible solutions:

    1. Add a getter for field 'quickstartFile'.
    2. Remove the annotations on 'quickstartFile'.

    Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.1.1/userguide/validation_problems.html#ignored_annotations_on_field for more details about this problem.
    BUILD FAILED in 35s

Comment: did you add `googleservices.json` file ??

Comment: yes @NajamUsSaqib